# how do i know the direction (unit vector) from an axis of THREE.AxisHelper?

Tags: three.js

I have a mesh with an added THREE.AxisHelper. The mesh rotate and traslate into the world and i need  to know the direction of the mesh x axis at a given time.

Comment: please share what you had already tested.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new method by copying the source code of `Object3D.getWorldDirection()`.

```
getWorldDirection: function () {

    var quaternion = new Quaternion();

    return function getWorldDirection( optionalTarget ) {

        var result = optionalTarget || new Vector3();

        this.getWorldQuaternion( quaternion );

        return result.set( 0, 0, 1 ).applyQuaternion( quaternion );

    };

}(),
```

and replace the z-axis `( 0, 0, 1 )` with the the x-axis `( 1, 0, 0 )`.

For efficiency, when you use the method, you can pass in the `optionalTarget` so a new `Vector3` is not allocated every time the method is called.

three.js r.80

Answer (score 1):

based on WestLangley resp., I have written this function:

```js
this.dirAirplane = new THREE.Vector3();
...
this.takeDir = function(){
  var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
  this.mesh.getWorldQuaternion( quaternion );
  this.dirAirplane.set(1,0,0).applyQuaternion(quaternion);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You are free to answer your own question, but please remember to "accept" answers of those who help you by clicking on the green checkmark.